# JPA annotations and Interfaces

Tags: jpa, java-ee-5

I have a class Animal and an interface it inherits from IAnimal.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Animal implements Serializable, IAnimal{...}.

@Entity
public class Jaguar extends Animal{...}
```

My first question is, do I need to annotate the interface?

I asked this because I am getting this error when I run my tests:

> Error compiling the query [SELECT s
>   FROM  animal s WHERE s.atype =
>   :atype].
>   Unknown abstract schema type
>   [animal]

If I remember correctly, before I added this interface it was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is occurring because you spelled Animal with a common a in the query. Try this:

```
 SELECT s FROM Animal s WHERE s.atype = :atype
```

Comment: just curious what a "common a" means.

Comment: @Thufir That is, "Lower case a". And this environment is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
SELECT s FROM Animal s WHERE s.atype = :atype
```

work? (just changed the case of animal)